# Matrix list index out of range

Tags: python, indexing

I've created a matrix like this:

```
b = [[0 for y in range(1,4)] for x in range(1,3)]
```

I want to have the indexes `b[1:2][1:3]` available, but the above code doesn't seem to do that.

`range(1,4)` should return numbers from 1 to 3, and `range(1,3)` should return numbers 1 and 2.

When i try to assign a value to `b[1][3]`, i get an IndexError. What is the explanation of this?

Comment: `b[1][3]` is the fourth element from the second sublist, you don't have  four elements `1, 2, 3 --> 3 elements`, you can only index from  `0-2`

Comment: Seeing what `b` actually is might help: `b = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]`

Comment: The index of a list starts always at zero `0`.

Answer (score 0):

`range(1,4)` is a list of length 3, therefore so is `[0 for y in range(1,4)]`. The indices available for a list are always from 0 up to the length of the list minus 1. If you want alternative indices use a dictionary.

```
>>> range(1, 4)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> for x in range(1, 4):
...     print(x)
...     
1
2
3
>>> L = [0 for y in range(1, 4)]
>>> L
[0, 0, 0]
>>> L[0]
0
>>> L[1]
0
>>> L[2]
0
>>> L[3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Thanks. Not sure why I thought I could make the indexing start at 1.